# How to transfer my windows 7 files to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, windows-7, files, transfer

Just installed Ubuntu, thinking I would be able to access my files under Windows 7 ... I was wrong.
How can I access them and transfer them to Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you install ubuntu on your HD erasing the Windows 7 OS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you chose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows during instalation (if you chose to erase Windows and dedicate your whole HD to Ubuntu, you have a different problem):

Ubuntu (or pretty much any Linux-based OS) reads Windows files without a problem. You just need to open your file browser (in a fresh installation, it should look like a file-cabinet icon to the left of your screen), search for your Windows partition (look under "Devices", on the left part of the Files window), click it and go find your files. They should be under `/users/<your user name>/` (note there's no such thing as `C:` in Linux, it has a different way of naming partitions). Copying those files to your Ubuntu partition is as easy as it is under Windows: you can click-and-drag a rectangle around the desired files and drag them to your "Home" folder (top of Files left panel). Of course, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> also work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I install file browser?

Comment: @efp, it comes pre-installed with your system and should be visible in the left Panel (namely, the Launcher). If you can't find it, press Win and type "Files" in the search box that appears. This "window" that appears when you press Win is called Dash, BTW.

Comment: Left panel = Launcher

Comment: @efp, no problem. You can also show your appreciation by upvoting my answer (that marks it as helpful so other users can find it better). If you've managed to find your Windows files, you may also accept my answer by clicking on the checked mark below the voting icons. That'll give you a couple of reputation points. ;)